# A box contains 100 tickets numbered 1 to 100.What is the probability of drawing 2 tickets, given the following conditions...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So, a box contains $100$ tickets numbered $1,2,3,...,100$ and two tickets are chosen at random. It is given that the maximum number on the 2 chosen tickets cannot be more than $10$ and the minimum number on them is $5$. We need to find the probability of drawing such tickets.

So since the minimum number on the 2 tickets is $5$, one of them has to be $5$ and the other ticket has to be greater than $5$, which will also be the maximum among the tickets, which as given in the question, can't be greater than $10$.

So, the possible combinations we have for drawing such tickets are $(5,6),(5,7),...,(5,10)$ which are $5$ cases. There also exist cases with the reversed order, as in $(6,5),(7,5),...,(10,5)$. That makes it a total of $10$ favorable cases.

The total number of ways to choose $2$ distinct tickets out of $100$ is given by $^{100}C_2$, and factoring in the 2 possible arrangements, we get $^{100}C_2\cdot 2!$.

So, $P(E)=\dfrac{10}{2\cdot^{100}C_2}=\dfrac{5}{\frac{100}{2}^{99}C_1}=\dfrac{1}{990}$

I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong. My textbook doens't have a solution for this question and the answer is given to be $\dfrac19$.

Thanks!

Comment: Either the question or the answer is incorrect.

Comment: Probably there were not 100 tickets, but only 10.

Comment: It is curious to me that you went to the extra trouble of doubling both the number of favorable cases and of all cases, to impose an order on the unordered values you started with, instead of just not worrying about order in the first place. Lourrran is right - most likely the second $0$ in "$100$" was a typo, and their solution was $\frac 5{\binom{10}2}$, instead of your $\frac 5{\binom{100}2}$

Comment: The answer is incorrect. Even if we were just drawing one ticket, the chances of getting it between 5 and 10 are already smaller than 1/9. So it's even less if we're taking two tickets.

Comment: @Lourrran Apparently it was meant to be "conditional probability". If $A$ denotes the event where we draw two tickets, the minimum of which is $5$ and if event $B$ denotes drawing 2 tickets such that the maximum number on them is not more than $10$, then we're supposed to evaluate $P(A|B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either there's a typo in the question or you've slightly misunderstood it.

Option 1 (typo): The question meant to say there are 10 tickets, not 100. (Same as Lourran's comment on the original question.)

Option 2 (misunderstanding): The question meant to say: There are 100 tickets in the box and two are chosen at random. You are **given** that the maximum of the selected tickets is $\le 10$. Now, what is the probability that the minimum is exactly 5?

Based on the phrasing of your question, I somewhat suspect option #2 happened, but anyway either option results in basically the same math problem, and the method you described in your question will work fine.

Comment: I don't see how option 1 and 2 both are the same problem. I hope my comment under the question clarifies things.

Comment: Yeah, that clarification is kinda what I expected. That's the same as my "option 2".

In my answer, "option 1" and "option 2" are not exactly the same situation, but the calculation would end up the same either way. Like it doesn't really matter between "there are only 10 tickets" vs. "there are 100 tickets but we condition on the chosen tickets being $\le 10$". Either way, for this particular probability computation, only tickets 1-10 are relevant.